# Enforcing invariants for child entities in concurrent editing environments

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Given the invariant that a child collection cannot exceed x number of items, how can the domain **guarantee** such an invariant is enforced in a concurrent/web environment? Let's look at a (classic) example:

We have a `Manager` with `Employee`s. The (hypothetical) invariant states that a Manager cannot have more than *seven* direct reports (`Employee`s). We might implement this (naively) like so:

```
public class Manager {

    // Let us assume that the employee list is mapped (somehow) from a persistence layer
    public IList<Employee> employees { get; private set; }

    public Manager(...) {
        ...
    }

    public void AddEmployee(Employee employee) {

        if (employees.Count() < 7) {
            employees.Add(employee);
        } else {
            throw new OverworkedManagerException();
        }
    }
}
```

Until recently, I had considered this approach to be good enough. However, it seems there is an edge-case that makes it possible for the database to store *more* than seven employees and thus break the invariant. Consider this series of events:

1. Person A goes to edit Manager in UI
   *(6 employees in memory, 6 employees in database)*
2. Person B goes to edit Manager in UI
   *(6 employees in memory, 6 employees in database)*
3. Person B adds Employee and saves changes
   *(7 employees in memory, 7 employees in database)*
4. Person A adds Employee and saves changes
   *(7 employees in memory, **8 employees in database**)*

When the domain object is once again pulled from the database, the `Manager` constructor may (or may not) reinforce the `Employee` count invariant on the collection, but either way we now have a discrepancy between our data and what our invariant expects. How do we prevent this situation from happening? How do we recover from this cleanly?

Comment: We need more information about the context to tell. For instance, in a web application, the problem may not arise exactly as you imply it does, since Aggregates aren't typically loaded in memory until the beginning of each http request processing. 3. and 4. would need to be concurrent, i.e. 4. loads the Aggregate after 3. has loaded it but before it has saved it, for the problem to occur.

Comment: One might rebuild the domain model from input data from the view, and persist that. With a good ORM there's no need to pull the entity when persisting. This *would* lead to the situation above.

Comment: I beg to differ. Half of the benefit of big ORM's is their change tracking/unit of work functionality. The typical DDD impl will pull the entity via the ORM at the beginning of transaction and save it at the end. Transactions are 1, 2, 3 and 4 separately, not [1,3] and [2,4]. The short HTTP request/response lifecycle makes overlapping transactions rarer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Consider this series of events:

```
Person A goes to edit Manager in UI
(6 employees in memory, 6 employees in database)
Person B goes to edit Manager in UI
(6 employees in memory, 6 employees in database)
Person B adds Employee and saves changes
(7 employees in memory, 7 employees in database)
Person A adds Employee and saves changes
(7 employees in memory, 8 employees in database)
```

The simplest approach is to implement the database writes as a compare and swap operation.  All writes are working with a stale copy of the aggregate (after all, we're looking at the aggregate in memory, but the *book of record* is the durable copy on disk).  The key idea is that when we actually perform the write, we are also checking that the stale copy we were working with is still the live copy in the book of record.

(For instance, in an event sourced system, you don't append to the stream, but append to a specific position in the stream -- ie, where you expect the tail pointer to be.  So in a race, only one write gets to commit to the tail position; the other fails on a concurrency conflict and starts over.)

The analog to this in a web environment might be to use an eTag, and verify that the etag is still valid when you perform the write.  The winner gets a successful response, the loser gets a [412 Precondition Failed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.2).

An improvement on this is to use a better model for your domain.  [Udi Dahan wrote](http://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/):

> A microsecond difference in timing shouldn’t make a difference to core business behaviors

Specifically, if your model ends up in a different state just because commands A and B happen to be processed in a different order, your model probably doesn't match your business very well.

The analog in your example would be that both commands should succeed, but the second of the two should also set a flag that notes that the aggregate is currently out of compliance.  This approach prevents idiocies when an addEmployee command and a removeEmployee command happen to get ordered the wrong way around in the transport layer.

> The (hypothetical) invariant states that a Manager cannot have more than seven direct reports

A thing to be wary of -- even in hypothetical examples, is whether or not the database is the book of record.  The database seldom gets veto power over the real world.  If the real world is the book of record, your probably shouldn't be rejecting changes.

Comment: "If the real world is the book of record, your probably shouldn't be rejecting changes." That one is quite often overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

> How do we prevent this situation from happening?

You implement this behavior in your `Repository` implementation: when you load the `Aggregate`, you also keep track of the `Aggregate's` version. The version can be implemented as a unique key constraint of `Aggregate's` Id *and* a integer sequence number. Every `Aggregate` has it's own sequence number  (initially every `Aggregate` has sequence number 0). Before the `Repository` tries to persist it, it increments the sequence number; if a concurrent persist has occurred, the database behind the `Repository` will throw a "unique key constraint violated" kind of exception and the persisting will not occur. 
Then (if you have designed the Aggregate as a pure, non-side effect object as you should do in DDD!), you could transparently retry the command execution, re-running all the Aggregate's domain code, thus re-checking the invariants. Please note that the operation must be retried only if a "unique constraint violation" infrastructure exception occur, not in case the `Aggregate` throws a domain exception.

> How do we recover from this cleanly?

You could retry the command execution until no "unique constraint violation" is thrown.
I've implemented this retrying in PHP here: https://github.com/xprt64/cqrs-es/blob/master/src/Gica/Cqrs/Command/CommandDispatcher/ConcurrentProofFunctionCaller.php

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much a DDD problem as a persistence layer problem. There are multiple ways to look at this.

**From a traditional ACID/strong consistency perspective**

You need to have a look at your particular database's available concurrency and isolation strategies, possibly reflected in your ORM capabilities. Some of them will allow you to detect such conflicts and throw an exception as Person A saves their changes at step 4.

As I said in my comment, in a typical web application that uses the Unit of Work pattern (via an ORM or otherwise), this shouldn't happen quite as often as you seem to imply though. Entities don't stay in memory tracked by the UoW all along steps 1. to 4., they are reloaded at steps 3. and 4. Transactions 3 and 4 would have to be concurrent for the problem to occur.

**Weaker, lock-free consistency**

You have a few options here.

- Last-one-wins, where the 7 employees from Person A will erase those from Person B. This can be viable in certain business contexts. You can do it by persisting the change as a `employees = <new list>` instead of `employees.Add`.
- Relying on version numbers, as @VoiceOfUnreason described.
- Eventual consistency with compensation, where something else in the application checks the invariant `(employees.Count() < 7)` after the fact, outside of Person A and B's transactions. A compensating action has to be taken if a violation of the rule is detected, like rollbacking the last operation and notifying Person A that the manager would have been overworked.